# How do I toggle a link (not button) to display and hide text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a text bounded by anchor tag. As soon as the user click it, it should toggle between two texts.

I have knowledge on how to toggle a button in JQuery, but don't know how do I implement it with link.

```
<h1>Questions and Answers</h1>
<p>First Question: What is the capital of Germany?
    <br>
    <i>Click <b><a id="toggle_this"></a>Here</a></b> to show/hide answer!</i>
</p>
<p>Answer: Berlin.</p>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("toggle_this").click(function() {
      $(this).hide();
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: `$("toggle_this")` your selector is wrong, that is looking for an element named toggle_this ie: `<toggle_this>`

Comment: You forgot the # in the selector. Also I suggest reading Rejith answer :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First change `id` to `class="toggle_this"`. Then use selector `.toggle_this`.

Then you can use `e.preventDefault()` to stop the default action if the link.
Then using `closest()` and `next()` you can get the answer `<p>` then `toggle()` it.

```
$(".toggle_this").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('p').next().toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do this using jQuery (you can also use plain ol' JS, but it looks like you're using jQuery from before), using the `.on` method.
Although, I would first recommend you adding a class/id to the answer, so it's a bit cleaner:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#toggle_this').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#answer').toggle();
  });
});
```

EDIT: `event.preventDefault()` prevents the anchor tag from navigating to the href, and `.on` registers an event handler, so that the function specified is executed when the event triggers.

Answer (score 0):

First you have a stray closing anchor `</a>` tag before the 'Here'.
Also i'd give the `<p>` your trying to hide an id eg. `<p id="answer">`.

Update the jQuery to this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#answer").hide();
    $("#toggle_this").click(function() {
      $("#answer").toggle();
    });
});
```